# How to create a temp table in Dbeaver from a csv file?

Tags: sql, csv, dbeaver

I am brand new to Dbeaver and came from using Microsoft SQL Server. Right now I am just using it to connect to a csv file.

I want to create a temp table from the table I have in there that was brought in from a csv file.  In SQL Server I would have done this:

```
select *
into #temptable
from mytable
```

What's the equivalent in Dbeaver?

Comment: Dbeaver connects to datasources and uses the features provided by the datasource. CSV files are just text files, and text files don't provide services such as temp tables.

Comment: I don't have the time to write this up/transcribe as an answer (if anyone else wishes to do it, by all means). But check out this site: https://justnumbersandthings.com/post/2018-06-12-dbeaver-import-csv/ it has a good walk through of how to establish the two connections and perform the load from CSV->SQL table with built in dbeaver featuresets.

Comment: Following the above guide I encountered an error when DBeaver tried to use two conflicting character collations for unknown reasons, one being Swedish (all my columns were numbers).  I ended up just copy-pasting chunks of the CSV into an import statement.

Answer (score 1):

This is not specific to DBeaver, but to PostgreSQL.
The way to create temporary tables in PostgreSQL with a SELECT query is:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temptable AS
SELECT *
FROM mytable;
```